# Caps lock key swaps back to default after minute or so after I set it with setxkbmap

Tags: keyboard, xfce, swap

Im trying to swap caps with control in last ubuntu xfce4 windows manager. I googled alot of variants, and fastest was `/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"`
but it auto swapped back after a minute or so.

And iI don't know which program swapped it back. Any advice ?

Comment: How many keyboard layouts have you defined - what are they?

Comment: I have installed a plugin which is used for layout switching. And this plugin is reseting Caps to default caps if is in action. But if i tune layouts and remove layout plugin from panel, everything is good

Comment: hmmm - can you give exact details of the plugin you are using - how installed, where from etc.

Comment: just with `apt-get install xfce4-xkb-plugin`
which another info do you need ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are experiencing this [bug on bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6321) - and reported also on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-xkb-plugin/+bug/548631).

Upstream says this is fixed - however this has not been backported on Natty.

Whilst I don't normally recommend installing deb packages from different versions of Ubuntu - in this case, the package is simple without dependencies - and the launchpad bug recommendation is similar.

I recommend that you download the oneiric deb (do not add the oneiric repository) and install it.

i.e. 32bit from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-xkb-plugin/0.5.4.1-1/+build/2589013), and [64bit](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-xkb-plugin/0.5.4.1-1/+build/2589011) from here.

```
sudo dpkg -i <name of the deb file downloaded>
```

Comment: ok. i will try to install a newest version